# KafkaConsumer#poll always returns null with Kafka clients version 0.8.2

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have written a minimal Kafka consumer code using `kafka-clients-0.8.2.0` API.

Surprisingly call to `KafkaConsumer#poll` method was always returning `null`. I checked the source code of KafkaConsumer and it turned out that the `poll` method is hardcoded to return `null` always.

```
@Override
public Map<String, ConsumerRecords<K,V>> poll(long timeout) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java

I am curious whether why it is kept like that. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a bug in kafka-clients library. Version 0.8.1 doesn't even have consumer package, so as for me, it's just wasn't implemented yet at that point of time when 0.8.2 was released. Of course returning null by using eclipse auto-generated method it's very bad practice. Instead, there are should be some kind of exception with `not yet implemented` message at least or something similar, but it is what it is...

Use kafka-clients 0.9.0 instead, That version contains poll method implementation.